# Issue in GWT Application Compilation

Tags: gwt

Hi, I am Compiling GWT Application in NetBeans 7.3.1 on a windows 7 64bit machine
and i'm getting the following issue:

```
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
C:\Users\taha\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Sales Processing Systm\nbproject\build-gwt.xml:330: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\taha\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Sales Processing Systm\nbproject\build-gwt.xml:479: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 55 seconds)
```

Comment: Set the log level to DEBUG and attach the logs

Comment: What's in build-gwt.xml at line 330 & 479?